# Disable Cipher SSL3_RSA_WITH_SEED_SHA in Postfix

Tags: ssl, postfix, email-server

I want to disable cipher SSL3_RSA_WITH_SEED_SHA in Postfix.

I have got in main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1,!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, DES, 3DES, MD5, DES+MD5, RC4
```

What should I add to smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers to exclude SSL3_RSA_WITH_SEED_SHA?

Comment: Isn't that already disabled as you have disabled the whole SSLv3 protocol? (`SSL3_RSA_WITH_SEED_SHA` sounds SSLv3 specific?)

Comment: I was thinking the same but I have done scan with OpenVAS and I am still getting `weak ciphers are: SSL3_RSA_WITH_SEED_SHA on port 465/tcp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use BetterCrypto document for a secure configuration.
After that, OpenVAS should not trigger any problem.

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high
tls_high_cipherlist=EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
```

Page 26, Section 2.3.4.Postfix: https://bettercrypto.org

Please read Limitations, too.

I hope to be useful.